# Word choice: ながらも vs. からこそ

Tags: grammar, word-choice, jlpt

I'm practicing JLPT mock test and there's the following sentence:

> どうしても時間がないと言う人でも、一日に15分くらいは捻出できるだろう。（中略）
>   「時間がない」と嘆く前に、まずは一日15分間の勉強を始めてみる。なかには、時間が**＿＿**できる勉強というのもある。

「短い**ながらも**」and「短い**からこそ**」are two choices. IMO, I think that 短い**ながらも** is the right answer but the correct answer is 短い**からこそ**. I don't understand why it is so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both 時間が短い**ながらも**できる勉強というのもある and 時間が短い**からこそ**できる勉強というのもある make sense on their own, but only the latter fits the context naturally.

「なかには ～ **も**ある」 ("There is *even* ～") implies the author is trying to introduce something special and non-straightforward. 時間が短い**ながらも**できる勉強がある ("the study you can do although there is not much time") is not surprising any more to the reader who has read the article this far, is it?

時間が短い**からこそ**できる勉強 ("the study you can do all the better because there is not much time") is a new piece of information, which can naturally be used with 「なかには～もある」 here.